# Business Logic Architecture with Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, repository-pattern, dao, unit-of-work

I`m using Entity Framework and I have entities like this:

```
    public class User : IEntity
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public String Email { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Project> UserProjects { get; set; }
    }

public class Project : IEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }

    public String Title { get; set; }

    public String Description { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserOwner")]
    public int UserOwnerId { get; set; }
    public virtual User UserOwner { get; set; }
}
```

Also I use Repository pattern and Unit Of Work pattern.
For example I have method 
CreateProject(String title, String description, String userOwnerEmail)
in Projects logic class which contains only Project Repository.
Also i have UserLogic class that allows me get user by his email.

How i can get user by his email in CreateProject method to designate him like a project owner.

The main aim is to create loose coupling method.

I think that this example is bad:

```
    public void CreateNewProject(String projectName, String description,String usersEmail)
    {
        var usersLogic = kernel.Get<IUsersServices>();
        User owner = usersLogic.GetUserByEmail(usersEmail);
        unit.Repository<Project>()
            .Insert(new Project
                {
                    Title = projectName,
                    Description = description,
                    CreationDate = DateTime.Now,
                    UserOwner = owner,
                    UsersIncludeedInProject = new List<User>()
                });
        unit.Save();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Business Logic and Entity Framework (or any other ORM) don't belong in the same phrase. Separation of Concerns is the principle.

```
class Project
{
     public Project(IProjectRepository repo, IUsersServices userServ){}

     public void CreateNewProject(String projectName, String description,String usersEmail)
      {
          var owner=_users.GetByEmail(usersEmail);

           //create project\\

          _repository.Save(project);
       }
```

One other approach is to pass the User object as an argument, object you'll get by asking a UserService or even a UserRepository to GetUserByEmail(). But it will be outside the CreateNewProject method

```
var user= _usersService.GetByEmail();
var project=project.CreateNewProject(projectName,projectDescription,user);
_projectRepository.Save(project);
```

In this case CreateNewProject does exactly that, because it's probably not its concern to save the project. I recommend this second approach.

Comment: But if i want to abstragate data layer entities and use data transfer objects. In this case my business layer shouldn't know about entities. var user= _usersService.GetByEmail(); - this will be incorrert. Please correct me if I`m wrong.

Comment: Maybe I forget to say that application is wep api project, but I think that it doesn`t matter.

Comment: The repository/Service will return application entities, an User object suitable to that context. That is not the User EF entity. The Service will use EF to query the db and then it maps the result to the business User object

Comment: But I`m still wondering: Is it good idea to abstagate entities in web service application, because client should have same database structure.

Comment: Wait it means, that i must copy almost all my EF model, to business objects. I mean that in most reasons it will have same structure.

Comment: Usually the business objects have a different structure than EF entities. I don't understand where the entity abstraction is. There are simply 2 different entities : one for business and other for EF. If the business object is identical with the Ef entity, this means you don't really have a business layer. But all this should be happening in the web service. Why do I ge the feeling the code you posted is a ApiController method?

Comment: No I posted only entities in my DAL library and method from business logic library

Comment: The main problem is that client application(on iPad) will have almost identical database structure, and it will synchronize database with server database.